# What is amssymb.sty package?

Tags: packages

The thesis latex template of my university has `\usepackage{amssymb}` Can someone please explain what that package does?

Comment: AMS is American Mathematical Society and sometime last century they commissioned the development of some math symbol fonts and `amssymb` is the LaTeX definitions accessing those fonts things like `\precneqq`

Comment: The answer lies at the end of a Google search: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbay.uchicago.edu%2Ftex-archive%2Ffonts%2Famsfonts%2Fdoc%2Famssymb.pdf&ei=y3OeUpSBD8eHkAWeq4H4CA&usg=AFQjCNFE5uxTDKfAj6QKzw10tqDFcBOQ1g&sig2=Yo_MGfP-hsXV0bCauxCZ3w&bvm=bv.57155469,d.dGI

Comment: Dear downvoter: Why a downvote? Question may be naive but, you know we don't know the situation  other people are in. :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar I didn't downvote, but I understand the downvoter. See my comment above. I don't think TeX.SE can afford to encourage this type of question, because the latter falls into the "minimal effort" category, as explained [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks). MLT, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask.

Comment: @HarishKumar I understand where you're coming from. We can argue about the best thing to do in a case like this, but I'd rather not give any positive feedback to a behaviour we're trying to discourage.